# How to stroke from top-center of rounded rectangle

Tags: html, css, svg, rect

I want to make a button out of SVG and replicate the YouTube's autoplay circle. I have been trying to get the stroke to start and end at the top-center, but it will start best at the top-left corner, because when I start changing stroke-dasharry and stroke-dashoffset numbers around it starts to go off at the start or end. I know this would be a lot easier with a circle, but I want to see if this is at all possible. It is starting to seem that it is not.

```css
svg:hover {
  stroke-dasharray: 1000;
  stroke-dashoffset: 1000;
  animation: dash 5s linear forwards;
}
@keyframes dash {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg width="160" height="80">

  <a xlink:href="/next_video" target="_self">
    <rect class="path" height="70" width="130" y="5" x="5" rx="35" stroke="#eee" stroke-width="8px" />
    <rect height="60" width="120" y="10" x="10" rx="30" fill="#00a6bc" />
    <text fill="#eee" text-anchor="middle" y="45" x="70">Next video</text>
  </a>
</svg>
```

Comment: That's the default behaviour, I'm not sure it CAN be changed.

Comment: You'd have to replace the rectangle by a path that started at the right place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to change the start position of the dash of a SVG `<rect>`.

To achieve what you want, you need to switch to a `<path>` element and draw its shape yourself.  Then you can start the path wherever you wish.

```css
svg:hover {
  stroke-dasharray: 1000;
  stroke-dashoffset: 1000;
  animation: dash 5s linear forwards;
}
@keyframes dash {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg width="160" height="80">

  <a xlink:href="/next_video" target="_self">
    <path d="M70,5 L100,5 A35,35 0 0 1 100,75 L40,75 A35,35 0 0 1 40,5 Z"
          stroke="#eee" stroke-width="8px" />
    <rect height="60" width="120" y="10" x="10" rx="30" fill="#00a6bc" />
    <text fill="#eee" text-anchor="middle" y="45" x="70">Next video</text>
  </a>
</svg>
```

Comment: How were you able to translate my rounded rectangle example to a path? I have been attempting to use GIMP to crudely draw the path by hand.

Comment: I did it by hand. I am familiar with SVG path syntax. It is not that difficult. You can learn for yourself by reading [the path section in the SVG specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html)

Comment: Wow, I did not think writing out the SVG path would be as feasible to do compared to using a SVG editor. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I could easily do it with SVGs, but I know I can do it with `div`s and pseudo elements wrapped up in some good ol'e fashioned CSS!

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WxROry

```
<div class="cont">
  <div class="rekt"><div class="rekt2"><span>Next Video</span></div></div>
</div>
```

Here's the HTML. For the CSS, just click the link; it's a bit longer than appropriate.

Comment: I like this example, but I was looking for a rounded rectangle. I am having difficulty applying any border-radius to the rekt class.