# Border animation start at top center

Tags: css, svg

[border animation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HjV35.png)

Right now I only know how to make it start from top left like this: https://codepen.io/joshua-leung/pen/mdmaRMQ 
I want to start the border draw animation from the top center like the picture above.
I think it's related to setting the correct `stroke-dasharray` and `stroke-dashoffset` but after experiments I still couldn't make it right.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to stroke from top-center of rounded rectangle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38018756/how-to-stroke-from-top-center-of-rounded-rectangle)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to change the shape to a path that starts at the desired location.

For example:

```css
html, body {
  background: rgb(20,20,20);
  text-align: center;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.svg-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
      margin: 0 auto;
  width: 320px;  
}
.shape {
  stroke-dasharray: 760;
  stroke-dashoffset: 760;
  stroke-width: 8px;
  fill: transparent;
  stroke: #19f6e8;
  border-bottom: 5px solid black;
  transition: stroke-width 1s, stroke-dashoffset 1s, stroke-dasharray 1s;
}
.text {
  font-family: 'Roboto Condensed';
  font-size: 22px;
  line-height: 32px;
  letter-spacing: 8px;
  color: #fff;
  top: -48px;
  position: relative;
}
.svg-wrapper:hover .shape {
  stroke-width: 2px;
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  stroke-dasharray: 760;
}
```

```html
<div class="svg-wrapper">
  <svg height="60" width="320" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path class="shape" d="M 160,0 H 320 V 60 H 0 V 0 H 160 Z"/>
    <div class="text">ZACH SAUCIER</div>
  </svg>
</div>
```